# Socket.io and Async Not Returning Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, async-await, es6-promise

I have a `async` client function that returns whether or not a username is taken. I am using socket.io for sending packets of data, and I am having trouble finding out what the issue is.

This is the function (Browser):

```
let socket = io();
async function createAccount(username, password){
    socket.emit('create account', {username:username, password:password});

    let res;

    await socket.on('create account return', (data) => {
        res = data.failed;
    });
    return res;
};
```

Here is my test script, which should log `true` if the username is valid, and `false` otherwise:

```
createAccount('bagel03', '12345').then((val)=>console.log(val));
```

Instead, I always get undefined, but if I change the `return` statement in the `createAccount` function to:

```
return true;
```

It works and logs `true`.

I am new to `async await` (this is my first project with it), and nothing online has been helping. What is the problem?

**EDIT**:
Here is the server code (Node.js):

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{ pingTimeout: 4000, pingInterval: 4000 })

io.sockets.on('connect',  socket =>{
    //account stuff
    socket.on('create account',  data =>{
        if(!isUsernameTaken(data.username)){
            id = addAccount(data);
            socket.emit('create account return',{failed:false})
        }else socket.emit('create account return', {failed:true})

    });
});
```

Comment: can you put the code from server? where you are declaring the events in socket.io?

Comment: Yea, I left that out becuase it's not too helpful, but sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `await` on an even listener. If you want to write your `createAccount` in order to be called with `await` you just need to make it to return a Promise. Something like:

```
let socket = io();
function createAccount(username, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    socket.emit('create account', {username:username, password:password});

    socket.once('create account return', (data) => resolve(data.failed));
  });
};
```

Comment: Note that this will still add a new listener every time and even attempt to resolve previous promises a second time when called again.

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT for pointing it out. I changed my answer: now using `socket.once` instead of `socket.on`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not using The websocket object in a right way.
every time you call `createAccount` you add a handler  to `'create account return'` event. For example, if you call `createAccount` 3 times,  you have 3 handlers on `'create account return'`.

Events are also `async` and whenever they are triggered ,event Handler will be called.
this is the simplest way that you can use it ,but it's better you wrap it in a class

```
let socket = io();
function createAccount(username, password){
    socket.emit('create account', {username:username, password:password});

};

function myHandler(data) {
   console.log(data.failed);
}

socket.on('create account return', myHandler);
```